# How to run the video streaming in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-streaming

I want to create one rails application. In that application i want to run the video streaming. I don't have any idea to do this. Anyone alreay attempts this help to me. Please tell where i want to start if you can please suggest some site to learn about video streaming in ROR.

Answer (score 2):

There is a rails cast for this  http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming

Answer (score 0):

This will teach you how to use html5 video with ogg in rails 
http://9elements.com/io/?p=306